# Hard expected value problem

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

Given a series of discrete random variables $Y_2, Y_3...Y_n$, such that for all $Y_i$ :

$P(Y_i = e^i) = \frac{1}{i}$, $P(Y_i = 3) = \frac{1}{3}$, $P(Y_i = X) = \frac{2}{3} - \frac{1}{i}$,

and $X$ is a random variable such that $P(X = 1) = \frac{2}{3}$, $P(x = -1) = \frac{1}{3}$. find $\mathbb{E}(Y_i)$ in terms of $i$.

I tried quite a lot of approaches to solve this but no success yet. First, I acknowledged that $P(Y_i = -1) + P(Y_i = 1) = P(Y_i =X)$, but I can't find another equation and so I can't find all of the probabilities for some $Y_i$.

Comment: Can you clarify the different values that $Y_i$ can take?

Comment: e^i, 3, 1 and -1

Comment: Side observation: Especially with one of the possible values being $e^i$, $i$ is an unfortunate choice of a dummy variable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Law of Total Expectation: $\begin{align}\Bbb E(Y_i) = \Bbb E(\Bbb E(Y_i\mid X)) \end{align}$

For clarrity, let us define $\mathsf P_{i}(y):=\Pr(Y_i{=}y)$

$$\begin{align}\Bbb E(Y_i) &= \Bbb E(\Bbb E(Y_i\mid X))\\[1ex]&= \Bbb E\big(e^i\mathsf P_{i}(e^i)+3\mathsf P_{i}(3)+X\mathsf P_{i}(X)\big)\\[1ex]&= e^i\mathsf P_{i}(e^i)+3\mathsf P_{i}(3)+\Bbb E\big(X\mathsf P_{i}(X)\big)\\[1ex]&~~\vdots \end{align}$$

Comment: im sorry' but i cant understand how you got the inner conditional expectation. I reckon the probabilities should be the conditional ones, and if so- how did you decide they are just equal to the original probabilities ?

Comment: For a given value of $X$, we see that $Y$ may realise the values $\{e^i, 3, X\}$ with the provided probabilities, $\{\mathsf P_i(e^i),\mathsf P_i(3),\mathsf P_i(X)\}$, so therefore the conditional expectation for $Y$ given $X$ is...

Comment: Alternatively you can see for $x\in\{-1,1\}$ we have $\Pr(Y{=}x)=\Pr(Y{=}X\mid X{=}x)\cdot\Pr(X{=}x)$.

Comment: I don't know what im missing here, i still dont see why the probabilities from the inner conditional expectation, that Y = e^i and that Y = 3 shouldnt be conditional probabilities, given that X = x.  How did you come to realize that they are equal ?

Comment: could you maybe elaborate on why theses conditional probabilities are equal to the original ones ?

Comment: i am familiar that if these events are independent then you can conclude this. I just cant see why you figured that they are. I tried quite a lot to calculate this joint probability but no success. Is this coming from common sense? or is there some mathematical machinery behind it ?

Comment: The events of $\{Y_i=e^i\}$ and $\{Y_i=3\}$ are independent of what value $X$ may be.  The event of $\{Y_i=-1\}$ is the event $\{Y_i=X, X=-1\}$, and likewise $\{Y_i=1\}$ is the event $\{Y_i=X, X=1\}$.  So $$\small\mathsf E(Y)=e^i\Pr(Y_i=e^i)+3\Pr(Y_i=3)+(-1)\Pr(Y_i=X)\Pr(X=-1)+1\Pr(Y_i=X)\Pr(X=1)$$

Answer (score 0):

We remove $X$ from this by saying that $P(Y_i=X)= \frac23-\frac1i$ is the same as saying $P(Y_i=1)= \frac23(\frac23-\frac1i)$ and $P(Y_i=-1)= \frac13(\frac23-\frac1i)$

Then, $E[Y_i]=y_iP(Y_i=y_i)=e^i(\frac1i)+3(\frac13)+1(\frac23(\frac23-\frac1i))-1(\frac13(\frac23-\frac1i))=\frac{e^i}i+1+\frac49-\frac2{3i}-\frac29+\frac1{3i}=\frac{e^i}i+\frac{11}9-\frac1{3i}$

Comment: why ? this is true if Yi = X and Yi = 1 are independent isnt it ?..which doesnt seem like it from a first glance.

Comment: This follows from $P(Y=x)=P(Y=X|X=x)P(X=x)$